# How do I $push a value to an array within an embedded document in MongoDB using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

It seems this may be an open issue with MongoDB, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831, but I'm not sure if there's actually a solution and I'm just thinking about and researching things in the wrong way.

Here is a subset of my schema:

```
var myModel = new mongoose.Schema({

  arrayA: [{
    subArrayA: [{
        fieldA: String
    }],
    subArrayB: [{
        fieldB: String
    }]
  }],

});
```

I want to update subArrayA by pushing a value into it. I've tried doing this in various ways with no success. This is the simplest attempt:

```
myModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.mymodel.arrayA.id(req.params.id), {
        $push: {
            subArrayA: {
                fieldA: valA
            }
        }
}, function(err) {
     // some stuff
});
```

This works fine when pushing directly to arrayA. For example, the code below executes the way I'd hope - by pushing a value into arrayA:

```
myModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.mymodel.id, {
    $push: {
        arrayA: {
            fieldA: valA
        }
    }
}, function(err) {
     // some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the MongooseArray method 'push'.

```
req.mymodel.arrayA.id(req.params.id).subArrayA.push({fieldA:ValA});

req.mymodel.save(function (err) {
    // some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation). This is a way of specifying sub-elements of objects without specifying the whole thing.

But you did specify an actual model you your schema did you not:

```
var Model = mongoose.model( "Model", myModel );
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.mymodel.arrayA.id(req.params.id), {
        "$push": {
            "arrayA.subArrayA": {
                "fieldA": valA
            }
        }
}, function(err) {
     // some stuff
});
```

So now you can notate an update without overriding the whole object at a given level.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I came across the dot notation earlier and tried just what you've suggested above. The document isn't updating and I'm not receiving an error. I was thinking I may have to modify the first parameter in the findByIDAndUpdate, since I'm referencing arrayA within the $push and targeting it in the find parameter...not sure what that would look like or if it's necessary.

Comment: @JayTolla What error? This matches the structure you are specifying so the error must be about something else.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error. The document isn't updating and no error is being thrown. The "// some stuff" I've referenced is executing, but the entry isn't appearing in the database.

Comment: @JayTolla did you actually define a model? And did you actually call `mogoose.connect`? And are you aware that the model names "plauralize" by default? So the collection will be "models" in this case. See the extra content.

Comment: Yup. The last bit of code I posted works properly as do other pieces of the application.